# Why text elements are randomly positioned?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone please explain why these (text 1-5) are not under each other and instead randomly positioned? (screenshot below)

```css
.container1{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  margin: 10px;
}


.container-fluid{
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 320px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}


.wrapper .sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: black;
}

h5{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul><li>Text-1</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Text-2</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Text-3</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Text-4</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Text-5</li></ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: use `.wrapper .sidebar ul li {display:block}`

Comment: Just tried, not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using flex in sidebar and sidebar ul.

```
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

When I run your code in w3schools, it works just fine however.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank a lot it works with the CSS above! The question is then why it works in W3 without it but dosent work in browser?

Comment: For me, when I ran your code snippet here, it works for me even then in chrome. You should check which browser you are testing it on. Sometimes different browsers have different display style for default elements.Using flex makes it consistent every where.